# Trouble posting XML string to HTTP Android HttpPost and HttpUrlConnection

Tags: android, xml, http-post, httpurlconnection

I am a little new to Android and have been struggling with an HTTP Post of an XML string. Ive tried about 5 versions of this code using both HttpsUrlConnection and HttpPost and the trouble that Im running into is my XML string is not making it to the application on my server but the request and XML IS making it to the Apache server.
What I am trying to accomplish is to send a username and Pin in XML to my apache perl cgi XML on my server. I have done it using GET and works great but cant seem to get POST to work.
Any insight of what I might be doing wrong and specifically if my code looks ok to accomplish my goal would be greatly appreciated.Again i apologize if this is a very newbie question.
Thanks guys :)

The XML string that is coming in from the main activity is an ordinary XML that i add xmlsrc= to before sending to the function.

```
String xml = "<?xml version=\"1.0\"encoding=\"UTF-8\"?><UserRequesting><NewUser>joseph</NewUser><Password>123456789</Password></UserRequesting>";
```

This first snippet is my latest using HttpsUrlConnection:

```
public void fetchLoginXML(){
    Log.d(TAG, "IN fetch ");
    HttpsURLConnection urlc;
    OutputStreamWriter out = null;
    DataOutputStream dataout;
    BufferedReader in = null;

    try {
        URL url = new URL(urlValuser);
        Log.d(TAG, "Final URL: " + url);
        urlc = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        urlc.setHostnameVerifier(new AllowAllHostnameVerifier());
        urlc.setRequestMethod("POST");

        urlc.setDoOutput(true);
        urlc.setDoInput(true);
        urlc.setUseCaches(false);
        urlc.setAllowUserInteraction(false);
        urlc.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "text/xml");
        // perform POST operation
        Log.d(TAG, "Xml Source to POST: " + xmlsrc);
        String body = xmlsrc;
        OutputStream output = new BufferedOutputStream(urlc.getOutputStream());
        output.write(body.getBytes());
        output.flush();
        int responseCode = urlc.getResponseCode();
        in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(urlc.getInputStream()),8096);

        String response = "";

        String line = in.readLine();
        while (line != null) {
            response += line;
            line = in.readLine();
        }

        Log.d(TAG, "Post results Response Code " + responseCode);
        Log.d(TAG, "Post results Response " + response);

        in.close();

        factory = XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance();
        XmlPullParser myparser = factory.newPullParser();
        Log.d(TAG, "Setting myparser paramaters ");
        myparser.setFeature(XmlPullParser.FEATURE_PROCESS_NAMESPACES, false);
        Log.d(TAG, "Setting myparser input into xmldata ");
        myparser.setInput(new StringReader(response));
        Log.d(TAG, "send myparser to function parsexmlandstoreit ");
        parseXMLAndStoreIt(myparser);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Error Posting Data: " + e.toString());
    } finally {
        if (out != null) {
            try {
                out.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        if (in != null) {
            try {
                in.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My Second Version is using HttpPost:

```
public void postData(String sendData) throws Exception {
    // Create a new HttpClient and Post Header
    Log.d(TAG, "Sending Data: " + sendData);
    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("https://joes....");
    httppost.addHeader("Accept", "text/xml");

    try {
        StringEntity se = new StringEntity(sendData);
        se.setContentType("text/xml");
        httppost.setEntity(se);
        // Execute HTTP Post Request
        Log.d(TAG, "Execute HTTP POST");
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
        Log.d(TAG, "Message Sent :)");
        InputStream ips  = response.getEntity().getContent();
        BufferedReader buf = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(ips,"UTF-8"));

        if(response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode()!= HttpStatus.SC_OK)
        {
            Log.e(TAG, "Response: " + response.getStatusLine().getReasonPhrase());
            throw new Exception(response.getStatusLine().getReasonPhrase());
        }

        Log.d(TAG, "Response: " + response.getStatusLine().getReasonPhrase());
        String received = "";

        String line = buf.readLine();
        while (line != null) {
            received += line;
            line = buf.readLine();
        }

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String s;
        while(true)
        {
            s = buf.readLine();
            if(s==null || s.length()==0)
                break;
            sb.append(s);

        }
        buf.close();
        ips.close();
        sb.toString();

        factory = XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance();
        XmlPullParser myparser = factory.newPullParser();
        Log.d(TAG, "Setting myparser paramaters ");
        myparser.setFeature(XmlPullParser.FEATURE_PROCESS_NAMESPACES, false);
        Log.d(TAG, "Setting myparser input into xmldata ");
        myparser.setInput(new StringReader(received));
        Log.d(TAG, "send myparser to function parsexmlandstoreit ");
        parseXMLAndStoreIt(myparser);
    }
    catch (ClientProtocolException e)
    {
        Log.d(TAG, "Client Protocol Error: " + e);
        e.printStackTrace();
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        Log.d(TAG, "I/O Error: " + e);
        e.printStackTrace();
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    }
}
```

Comment: Please explain your server behind apache. What kind?

Comment: it is linux / apache 2.2

Comment: Nonsense. That's not an answer to my question. You were talking about 'a webserver application' isn't it?

Comment: i apologize greenapps, as I am still getting my footing. What i am interacting with is apache perl CGI XML. I will append my question

Comment: You should post your perl code too as then only we will know what your script expects.

Comment: Ok. I will have to gather that from my Perl Guy, i did not write that Perl Script. However, may I ask if the code here looks ok to accomplish the task of posting an XML in Android?

Comment: your code looks ok, and the fact that apache receives it confirms that.

Comment: thank you njzk2. All the other coders do not code in Java so i have no one to help or shed light on whether I was heading in the right direction or not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after a long time trying to understand why this would hit the apache server but not our application on the server i found that i needed to create a buffered body BEFORE POST and then write the buffered stream to the Server.

Like so :

```
  URL url = new URL(urlValuser);
        Log.d(TAG, "URL to POST to: " + url);
        HttpsURLConnection urlc = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        urlc.setReadTimeout(10000);
        urlc.setConnectTimeout(15000);
        urlc.setRequestMethod("POST");
        urlc.setDoInput(true);
        urlc.setDoOutput(true);
        // perform POST operation
        OutputStream os = urlc.getOutputStream();
        BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(os, "UTF-8"));
        writer.write(xmlToPost);
        writer.flush();
        writer.close();
        os.close();

        int responseCode = urlc.getResponseCode();
        in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(urlc.getInputStream()));
        String response = "";
        String line = in.readLine();
        while (line != null) {
            System.out.println(response);
            response += line;
            line = in.readLine();
        }
        Log.d(TAG, "Post results Response Code " + responseCode);
        Log.d(TAG, "Post results Response " + response);

        in.close();

        return response;
        writer.write(xmlToPost);
        writer.flush();
        writer.close();
        os.close();
```